# Symfony2 Twig extension: Creating form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I wanted to have a contact-form-block that i can reuse on different pages and templates. So i decided to write a Twig extension. The problem is that i cant access the createFormBuilder() function. The second problem will be then that i cant access the request object for validation. My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Name\NameBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ContactExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    function getName() {
        return 'contact_extension';
    }

    function getFunctions() {
        return array(
           'contactform' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'contactform'),
        );
    }

    function contactform() {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
           ->add('Name', 'text')
           ->add('Message', 'textarea')
           ->add('Send', 'submit')
           ->getForm();

        return $this->render('NameBundle:forms:contactform.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    }
}
```

But i get error "Call to undefined method createFormBuilder()"...

Also i will get error if i change the function to `function contactform(Request $request) { ... }`

What do i need to add to use this function an object? Or maybe the twig extension is the completely wrong approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createFormBuilder()` is a [Controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php) helper that allows you to access the `form.factory` service within your controllers through the container (code below)

```
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;
// ...
class Controller extends ContainerAware
{
    // ...
    public function createFormBuilder($data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, $options);
    }
```

You're **not** in a "Controller context" here, so if you want to use the `form.factory` service within your extension you've to **inject it**.

**BUT,**

**I'll not advice your to** manage your `contactForm` this way (using a Twig Extension function). Why don't you just create a `contactAction` within the appropriate controller. You can then render your form in your templates using the twig `render` helper,

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:YourController:contactAction')) }}
```

Comment: this give me Undefined property $container   
(i just copied this function into my class)

Comment: You've to understand my answer. I didn't advice you to add this method to your extension, I just pointed to the one used for Controllers to help you understand what this method is used for.

Comment: So... how do I inject it? :)

Comment: I'll not advice your to manage your contactForm this way (using a Twig Extension function). Why don't you just create an action contactAction within your controller. Which you can render in your templates using the twig render helper, {{ render(controller('YourBundle:YourController:contactAction')) }}

Comment: A much cleaner solution indeed!

Comment: problem now is that i cant pass the request object to the controller? (for validation, sending mail, etc)

Comment: What about using the app.request global variable on twig.

Comment: This is now sending me mails `{{ render(controller('NameBundle:Default:contact', {'request': app.request})) }}` BUT it doesnt show my flash messages and if i try `return $this->redirect()` it gets me an exception "Error when rendering" ... is it THAT hard to write a simple form block in symfony? or am i too stupid?

Comment: I think it's better to use Ajax calls to handle your contact Form if you want to embed it using the render twig helper.

Comment: @AhmedSiouani Any comment on why you dont recommend the twig extension approach? IMO, its more cleaner and versatile.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Symfony to make your code clear you should make Forms (src/forms) in diffrent file and just call it in your view and controller.